# How to avoid the squizzle for "for...in" in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have squizzle for `object[property]` in

```
  const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

  for (const property in object) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
  }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsWBeGBvGBDAXDAIwA0M8hATGcIQMwwC+A3AFCsBmIATjABShIsAA7cQw5NygBPGAEswcJKigBKbKxgxBEEABtkAOj0gA5nwAGAEiyjxkmY0I2EKNAG07EqdIC6jC1U2RnYAelCYZAAPCTRkABM4AFcoYRT8VnCYACICYmzMiOyKGEoCrOzaGDoCzRggA)

Answer (score 2):

`for..in` iterates over property names, and property names are strings, so `property` is typed as a string - but `object` has `a`, `b`, `c` properties, rather than being typed as having generic `string` properties.

Extract both the key and value at once with `Object.entries`:

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${value}`);
}
```

Or assert that the property is a key of the object:

```
for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property as keyof object]}`);
}
```

Or type the object as having generic `string` keys:

```
const object: { [prop: string]: unknown } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

Comment: Why Typescript doesn't by default use `keyof object` for the type of the property variable in `for … in` loops escapes my mind.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has something to do with inherited properties.